# Different require ways of modules in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I'm very confusing using request modules on nodeJS. I can´t understand the following foundation about the many manners to require this modules.

This snipet that's correct but, Why has it to be in this way?

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    router = express.Router(),
    assert = require('assert'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

For example, `assert` have methods and `express` too, so, why it can't be declared directly in the `app` variable?

```
var app = require('express'); // like assert = require('assert')
```

...And about the MongoClient, Whay I can't do in the same way of `router` declaration?

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient();
```

Comment: because `app` !== `express`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first example, note that `app = express()` is completely different to `app = express`. The former assigns the result of calling a function, while the latter is equivalent to your suggestion that won't work. You could do the following if you really like repetition, but then you won't have a reference to the `express` module:

```
var app = require('express')(),
    router = require('express').Router()
```

For your second example, again you're confusing assignment of a function with assignment of the result of a function call. A correct (but with an unnecessary extra line) alternative would be:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient
```

In short there's only one way to require a module - `require('nameOrPath')` - everything else is unrelated to the module system.